# Aws codepipeline facing insufficient permission issue

Tags: bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to integrate codepipeline in Aws for bitbucket. Done all the setup and also grant permission for AWS CodeStar. But when running a pipeline in the Source step it is failing with an error

> Insufficient permissions "Ensure your source provider account has access to the repository"

[image: Codepipeline Error]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say you granted permission for AWS CodeStar, you granted Pipeline these permissions. By default, amazon aws enforces least privilege and so you also need to grant codestar permissions to the service role that the buildjob in CodeBuild is using.

In addition, if you are using "Full Clone" as your source type, you need to add sufficient permissions. Here is a full guide regarding this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#codebuild-role-connections